# How can I Change the TimeZone in my Python enviornment

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, pytz, python-3.8

Im building a bots for some clients but want the bots to activate at the same time based on Eastern time only, since Im in New York, and thats the only time I do know by heart. I don't know what timezone any of my future clients will be in so I'd rather permanently set it contingent upon eastern time. I want them all to be timed to start at 11:00AM EST - US/Eastern

```
from pytz import timezone
import time, datetime



def Schedule():
    tz = timezone('US/Eastern')
    today = datetime.datetime.now(tz) 
    #today = datetime.datetime.now()
    Activate = (datetime.datetime(today.year, today.month, today.day, 0, 50, 0) - today).seconds 
#Uses Military Time 23, 25, 0 = 11:25:00PM                                                       
    print('Waiting for ' + str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=Activate)))
    time.sleep(Activate)
#Rest of the code will activate at the correct time that you set it

Schedule() #Uncomment this
```

Comment: although this is an interesting question from a technical point of view, don't you think it might be easier to just set up everything in UTC?